# Custom headers and footers with NLog

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

I am trying to add some targets to NLog that log certain details out to a separate XML file for analysis. I have been trying to get NLog to generate fully valid XML that is in a schema different than the `Log4JXmlEventLayout` provider.

Towards this end, I've been using a file target that has a header  (for the XML declaration and root element opening) and footer (for the root element closing), like so:

```
<target name="someFileTarget" xsi:type="File" fileName="afile.xml"
       header="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;my-events&gt;" 
        footer="&lt;/my-events&gt;">
  <layout xsi:type="SimpleLayout">
    <text><![CDATA[<event><timestamp>${longdate}</timestamp></event>]]> </text>
  </layout>
</target>
```

However, the footer (closing element) never gets written to the log file, even after the log file gets rolled over. Is there something about this configuration that is incorrect?

I also attempted the `LayoutWithHeaderAndFooter` provider (as documented here: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/LayoutWithHeaderAndFooter), but this did not appear to work at all and no events were written to the target.

Comment: The process is logging to a file and the NLog version is 2.1.0. Manually calling `LogManager.Shutdown()` causes the footer to be written at the time of execution, but the footer still does not get written out at log roll time.

Comment: Try forcing a flush/shutdown ... `LogManager.Flush(); LogManager.Shutdown();` I've read that not flushing causes issues in Mono. Perhaps a similar issue in your case?